# Initialization with empty curly braces

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, explicit

First attempt and everything works fine:

```
class Base {
 public:
    Base() {std::cout << "default ctor!\n"; }
};
...
Base b{};
Base b_one = {};
```

Another way of implementation(add `explicit`):

```
class Base {
 public:
    explicit Base() {std::cout << "default ctor!\n"; }
};
...
Base b{};
Base b_one = {};  // error! Why?
```

I have read on cppreference that in both cases default initialization would be used and no diffences.

From list initialization:

> Otherwise, If the braced-init-list is empty and T is a class type with a default constructor, value-initialization is performed.

From value initialization:

> if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I have read on cppreference that in both cases default initialization would be used and no diffences.

No they're not the same. To be precise, `Base b{};` is [direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#direct-list-initialization), while `Base b_one = {};` is [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization); for copy-list-initialization, only non-`explicit` constructor may be called.

(emphasis mine)

> - direct-list-initialization (**both explicit and non-explicit
>     constructors are considered**)
> - copy-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors
>     are considered, but **only non-explicit constructors may be called**)

Comment: Oh, thanks. Too simple question ;) So can you help with one more? What happens when we assign to already initialized variable `b_one = {}`

Comment: @GusevSlava `operator=` will be tried to called. If the default constructor of `Base` is not `explicit`, then `{}` is implicitly converted to `Base`, then copy assignment operator (`Base::operator=(const Base&)`) is called. If the default constructor is `explict`, then it'll fail because implicit conversion fails.