# How to initialize a struct to 0 in C++

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

Here is a related C answer that doesn't work (as a zero initializer for a struct) in C++: [Initializing a struct to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152160/initializing-a-struct-to-0). One of the solutions presented is this:

```
myStruct _m1 = {0};
```

This works fine in C, but it doesn't work in C++. :( :

> error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'myScope::MyStruct' with an rvalue of type 'int'`.

How do you zero-initialize a struct in C++?

### Related:

1. Initializing
   a struct to 0 in C: [Initializing a struct to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152160/initializing-a-struct-to-0)
2. Update: (an adjacent, but NOT duplicate question which also turns out to be very useful) [Initialization with empty curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862128/initialization-with-empty-curly-braces)

### See also:

1. [adjacently-related, but is for C-style arrays, *not* structs] [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/4561887)

### To the people voting to close this question:

My question is not a duplicate of this other question ([Initialization with empty curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862128/initialization-with-empty-curly-braces)), as this other question isn't asking about the various ways to initialize a struct in C++ and why the C way doesn't work, rather, they are asking **why does the C++ keyword `explicit` break one of their initialization techniques**. Two distinct questions. Not duplicate.

### Follow-up question I asked:

1. [Why doesn't initializing a C++ struct to `= {0}` set all of its members to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531928/4561887)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialization with empty curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862128/initialization-with-empty-curly-braces)

Comment: No it doesn't, but it's related and still useful. I think they are two distinct questions.

Comment: " Back to Basics: Initialization in C++ - Ben Saks - CppCon 2023" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_23qmZtDBxg

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Before we start:

1. Let me point out that a lot of the confusion around this syntax comes because in both C and C++ you *can* use the `= {0}` syntax to initialize **all members of a C-style *array* to zero!** See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization. So, this works:

   > ```
   > // z has type int[3] and holds all zeroes, as: `{0, 0, 0}`
   > int z[3] = {0};
   > ```

   But, that syntax does *not* work the same for *structs*, which are entirely different animals than C-style arrays. Additionally, the various techniques allowed for the initialization of structs differ between C and C++.

   Going further, one should know that technically, `= {0}` only explicitly initializes the *first* element of an array to `0`, and the rest are implicitly automatically initialized to `0` since their values are *unspecified*, so they get value-initialized (zero-initialized for non-class types; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532116/4561887)) to `0`.

   These revised examples from the latest cppreference.com community wiki (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) make this even more clear. Notice in particular how the `int y[5] = {1,2,3};` example doesn't specify the last two elements, so they are implicitly default-initialized to zero, and the `int z[4] = {1};` example only explicitly initializes the first element to one, so all the rest are implicitly default-initialized to zero, and the `int w[3] = {0};` example only explicitly initializes the first element to zero, so all of the rest are implicitly default-initialized to zero:

   > ##### Initialization from brace-enclosed lists
   >
   > When an array is initialized with a brace-enclosed list of initializers, the first initializer in the list initializes the array element at index zero (unless a designator is specified) (since C99), and each subsequent initializer without a designator (since C99) initializes the array element at index one greater than the one initialized by the previous initializer.
   >
   > ```cpp
   > int x[] = {1,2,3}; // x has type int[3] and holds 1,2,3
   > int y[5] = {1,2,3}; // y has type int[5] and holds 1,2,3,0,0
   > int z[4] = {1}; // z has type int[4] and holds 1,0,0,0
   > int w[3] = {0}; // w has type int[3] and holds all zeroes
   > ```

   Again, though, the above examples are for *arrays*, and this answer is for *structs*. So, let's keep going.
2. See also my follow-up question I asked after writing this answer below: [Why doesn't initializing a C++ struct to `= {0}` set all of its members to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531928/4561887)

---

Back to the answer:

I figured it out: to get it to compile, just delete the zero:

```cpp
// does NOT work in C++ (but *does* work in C)
myStruct _m1 = {0}; 

// works in both C and C++!
myStruct _m1 = {};
```

It now compiles. However, I ran a bunch of tests to check some things in my [struct_initialization.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/struct_initialization.cpp) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo, and using `= {}` does NOT initialize all elements of the struct to *zero*! Rather, it initializes the struct to its *default values*, and is called "value initialization" (see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532117/4561887)). To run my tests and see for yourself, clone my repo above and run [`eRCaGuy_hello_world/cpp/struct_initialization_run.sh`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/struct_initialization_run.sh).

Assuming you have this struct:

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    int num1 = 100;
    int num2 = -100;
    int num3;
    int num4 = 150;
} data_t;
```

*Note: the `typedef` above is a carry-over from when I was testing this stuff in C instead of C++ (although the default struct values are not allowed in C, of course). For C++, this is preferred instead:*

```cpp
struct data_t
{
    int num1 = 100;
    int num2 = -100;
    int num3;
    int num4 = 150;
};
```

*So please ignore it wherever I unnecessarily use `typedef` to define the structs below.*

Anyway, if I declare one of the above `data_t` structs, and then do this:

```cpp
data_t d2 = {};
printf("d2.num1 = %i\nd2.num2 = %i\nd2.num3 = %i\nd2.num4 = %i\n\n",
        d2.num1, d2.num2, d2.num3, d2.num4);
```

...the output will be:

```
d2.num1 = 100
d2.num2 = -100
d2.num3 = 0
d2.num4 = 150
```

<s>And I'm not even sure if `d2.num3` is zero because it was initialized to zero or because it was left uninitialized, and that memory location happened to contain zero.</s>

What happens is that `= {}` sets all values to their *default values*, which are `100` for member `num1`, `-100` for member `num2`, and `150` for member `num4`. `num3` has no explicit default value set by us, so it gets *zero-initialized* as its implicit default value. Read these answers to [my follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531928/4561887):

1. [@NathanOliver's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532117/4561887):

   > When you have `T t{};` or `T t = {}` what you are doing is called [**value initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).  In value initialization, if the object/member does not have a default constructor, or a default member initializer, then the compiler falls back to zero initializing the objec/member.  So with
   >
   > ```cpp
   > data_t d{}
   > ```
   >
   > the value of the members in order would be 100, -100, 0 ,150 and that `0` for `num3` happens because it has no default and you did not provide a value in the `{}` so the compiler falls back to zero initializing `num3`.
2. [@rustyx's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532116/4561887):

   > `data_t d3 = {0}` is [*list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) syntax which, with aggregates such as `data_t`, performs [***aggregate initialization***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization): the provided `0` value is used to initialized the first member and the remaining members are initialized using their corresponding defaults, and if none exist, are *value-initialized* (*emphasis mine, edited for C++14*):
   >
   > > If the number of initializer clauses is ***less than*** the number of members or initializer list is completely empty, ***the remaining members*** are initialized by their [***default member initializers***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), if provided in the class definition, and otherwise by empty lists, in accordance with the usual [*list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) rules (which performs [*value-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.
   >
   > [*value-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) means zero-initialization for non-class types. *That* is why the member `num3`, which has no default value, gets the value `0`.
   >
   > Note: this is not to be confused with [*default-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), which does not initialize non-class types at all. `data_t d3;` would be *default-initialization*, and the member `num3` would be left in an indeterminate state.
   >
   > ...

As explained here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization, you can also do this:

```cpp
myStruct _m1{};
```

In the example above, this code:

```cpp
data_t d2{};
printf("d2.num1 = %i\nd2.num2 = %i\nd2.num3 = %i\nd2.num4 = %i\n\n",
        d2.num1, d2.num2, d2.num3, d2.num4);
```

...would produce output identical to what I showed above.

Even in cases where setting the struct to `= {0}` DOES work, such as this:

```cpp
// Does NOT do what I originally expected! Only sets the FIRST value in the 
// struct to zero! 
// The rest use default values, which are either 1) the explicit defaults if you 
// set them with `= some_num` or whatever in the struct definition, or which are
// 2) in C++ at least, the implicit default values of `0` if you did not set 
// explicit defaults.
data_t d3 = {0};
printf("d3.num1 = %i\nd3.num2 = %i\nd3.num3 = %i\nd3.num4 = %i\n\n",
        d3.num1, d3.num2, d3.num3, d3.num4);
```

...the output is still not what I originally expected, as it only sets the *first* value to zero! (<s>I don't understand why</s>; due to the hierarchy of *list/aggregate initialization* and *value initialization* (which zero initializes when explicit defaults are not set); see [my question here and the several answers there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531928/4561887)):

```
d3.num1 = 0
d3.num2 = -100
d3.num3 = 0
d3.num4 = 150
```

On C-style **arrays**, however (NOT structs), these semantics work fine. Refer to this answer here ([How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value/201116#201116)). The following lines, therefore, both set all elements of the C-style array to zero when using C++:

```cpp
uint8_t buffer[100] = {0}; // sets all elements to 0 in C OR C++
uint8_t buffer[100] = {};  // sets all elements to 0 in C++ only (won't compile in C)
```

*So, [after much experimentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), it looks like the following several ways are the ONLY ways to zero-initialize a struct, PERIOD. If you know differently, please comment and/or leave your own answer here.*

### The only ways possible to zero-initialize a struct in C++ are:

1. Be explicit:

   ```
    // C-style typedef'ed struct
    typedef struct
    {
        int num1 = 100;
        int num2 = -100;
        int num3;
        int num4 = 150;
    } data_t;

    // EXPLICITLY set every value to what you want!
    data_t d1 = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    // OR (using gcc or C++20 only)
    data_t d2 = {.num1 = 0, .num2 = 0, .num3 = 0, .num4 = 0};
   ```
2. Use `memset()` to force all bytes to zero:

   ```
    data_t d3;
    memset(&d3, 0, sizeof(d3));
   ```
3. Set all default values to zero in the first place:

   ```
    // C-style typedef'ed struct
    typedef struct
    {
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;
        int num4 = 0;
    } data_t;

    // Set all values to their defaults, which are zero in
    // this case
    data_t d4 = {};
    // OR
    data_t d5{}; // same thing as above in C++

    // Set the FIRST value only to zero, and all the rest
    // to their defaults, which are also zero in this case
    data_t d6 = {0};
   ```
4. Write a constructor for the C++ struct

   ```
    // 1. Using an initializer list
    struct data
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int num4;

        data() : 
            num1(0),
            num2(0),
            num3(0),
            num4(0) {}
    };

    data d7; // all values are zero

    // OR: 2. manually setting the values inside the constructor
    struct data
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int num4;

        data()
        {
            num1 = 0;
            num2 = 0;
            num3 = 0;
            num4 = 0;
        }
    };

    data d8; // all values are zero
   ```
5. Use a struct with no default values, and make your object you create from it `static`

   ```
    typedef struct
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int num4;
    } data_t;

    // `static` forces a default initialization of zero for each
    // value when no other default values are set
    static data_t d9;
   ```
6. So, if you have a struct with *non-zero* default values, and you want to zero all values, you must do it EXPLICITLY! Here are some more ways:

   ```
    // 1. Have a `constexpr` copy of the struct that you use to
    // reset other struct objects. Ex:

    struct data
    {
        int num1 = 1;
        int num2 = 7;
        int num3 = -10;
        int num4 = 55;
    };

    constexpr data DATA_ALL_ZEROS = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    // Now initialize d13 to all zeros using the above `constexpr` struct 
    // object
    data d13 = DATA_ALL_ZEROS; 


    // OR 2. Use a `zero()` member function to zero the values:

    struct data
    {
        int num1 = 1;
        int num2 = 7;
        int num3 = -10;
        int num4 = 55;

        zero()
        {
            num1 = 0;
            num2 = 0;
            num3 = 0;
            num4 = 0;
        }
    };

    data d14;
    d14.zero();
   ```

#### The big take-away here is that NONE of these: `data_t d{}`, `data_t d = {}`, and `data_t d = {0}`, actually set all members of a struct to zero!

1. `data_t d{}` sets all values to their defaults defined in the struct.
2. `data_t d = {}` also sets all values to their defaults.
3. And `data_t d = {0}` sets only the FIRST value to zero, and all other values to their defaults.

And in all cases above, if explicit default values are not set, the implicit default values are zero (`0`).

So, if you want particular values to be the defaults, **BE EXPLICIT**!

Note that the above key take-aways I wrote seem to contradict [this documentation on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), so it has led me to ask [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531928/4561887) listed just below, which has proven VERY helpful to my understanding!

### Going further

1. *MOST USEFUL*: **Follow-up question of mine:** [Why doesn't initializing a C++ struct to `= {0}` set all of its members to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531928/4561887)

### References

1. VERY USEFUL:

   1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization
   2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
   3. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization
2. VERY USEFUL: Initializing all members of an **array** (not struct) to the same value:

   1. [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value/201116#201116)
   2. [gcc only] [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value/207702#207702)
3. https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/struct_initialization.cpp

   1. Clone this repo and run the code yourself with `cpp/run_struct_initialization.sh`

### Related

1. [Initializing default values in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782103/initializing-default-values-in-a-struct)
2. *****[my own answer, which demonstrate this sort of struct modification/aggregate member reassignment within any function: `leds[0] = {10, 20,  30,  40,  50};`] [Arduino Stack Exchange: Initializing Array of structs](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80236/initializing-array-of-structs/80289#80289)

### Todo

1. [ ] I recently saw this in C: `my_struct_t my_struct = {{0}};`. Investigate what that does, and if it is valid only in C, for instance, but not C++.

   Update some weeks later in Jan. 2024: it appears to be an aggregate value initialization of a struct or list within a struct, in C. I think in C it would work for either a struct or list within a struct, but in C++ it would only work for a list within a struct, probably.

Comment: Note this syntax does not do zero-initialization if the struct type is not an "aggregate", for example, if it defines any constructors.

Comment: Makes sense! In such a case, if a constructor exists, I could use it to initialize members as I see fit anyway--setting them to zero or otherwise in the constructor or with an initializer list.

Comment: Why the downvote? It solved my problem perfectly, and I provided examples and references.

Comment: This syntax is not zero-initialization if the class has a user-provided constructor (in which case zero-initialization is not possible)

Comment: if `myStruct _m1 = {0};` did not compile, then chances are good that  the `{}` version will not do zero-initialization of all the subobjects

Comment: @M.M, alright, I did a ton of testing and completely rewrote the answer. Please check it over and see if you notice anything. The behavior of `data_t d = {0}` really threw me off, as not even it sets all values in the struct to zero! Rather, it sets only the *first* value in the struct to zero, which is super strange to me, and then it sets all the rest to their default values. See my repo in the bottom of the References to run and test a bunch of my test code.

Comment: "BE EXPLICIT" seems like overly specific advice.  The language is designed to give the type designer discretion in initialization.  In that light, you should revisit the question of whether you should be initializing to zero in the first place, or whether you should trust the defaults.  If you own the type, you should revisit the question of whether those defaults should actually be zero.   Having done that, if your considerations for a particular initialization are different than for those of the type's defaults, and you still must initialize to zero, **then** be explicit.

Comment: good summary for correct zero-init, however, a few examples are redundant, as they list different ways to do default ctors

Comment: @PavelP, please list out which examples and I can update the answer to point this out.

Comment: @GabrielStaples 3 and 4 (both cases) are effectively the same. Perhaps others are redundant as well.

Comment: @PavelP, to the compiler they may be the same, but to the programmer, myself included, I want to be aware of and knowledgeable about the existence of all practical options, so I'll leave all examples I have in 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

Objects in C++ are given the ability to control the values of any subobjects within them. As such, C++ has no mechanism that will force zero-initialization onto any object *in general*.

Objects with no user-provided constructors or default member initializers can undergo zero-initialization in two cases: if the variable is declared `static`, or if the object is being value-initialized. There are multiple syntaxes that will provoke value initialization of an object, including `T()`, `T{}`, and `T t = {};`, where applicable.

But other than that, if the creator of the type of an object does not want it to be zero-initialized, then you cannot impose that upon the object. You can ask for value-initialization or default-initialization, but whether either of these will invoke zero-initialization depends on the type.

Comment: Be careful with `()`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ for types with no constructor (id est trivially constructible), `{}` always initializes all bytes to zero, identically the same as `{ 0 }` in C.

```
PlainOldData pod{};
```

For types with a constructor, hence not trivially constructable, it makes little sense to initialize all bytes to zero as those objects are meant to control their own state. What you usually want is default initialization, which can usually be done with `{}`.:

```
Object obj{};
// or
Object obj;
```

You can go around this limitation and use `memset` to clear the memory, but be aware that it **will** cause a lot of problems with overwriting vtable pointers, et cetera.

```
memset(&obj, 0, sizeof obj); // dangerous for non-trivial objects
```

Comment: "id est" is not English. I think you may have mixed in some of your native language?

Comment: @GabrielStaples I believe it is Latin originated, commonly abbreviated to "i.e."

Comment: Ahhh...I use "ie" or "i.e." all the time, but never knew it was "id est". :)

Comment: But constrictor is still a snake and should be constructor?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't know what you mean by that